# iOS: SplitView show master with UIButton on detail

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I've developed an app that, on iPad, has a UISplitViewController.  The master view is a tableview embedded in a NavigationController.  The detail is not in a NavigationController (and I do not want it to be).  I've added a button to the detail that I want to show/ hide the master view.  I want the app to run on iOS 7.0 and later.  How could I  call the master view from button click in detail view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tutorial that answered my question.  You can find it here: http://www.dharmaworks.net/Consulting/switching-detail-views-in-uisplitviewcontroller-with-ios7/

Answer (score 1):

First, override the following delegate method:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```

and use it to grab a reference to the bar button item, and store it in an iVar:

```
barButtonForMaster = barButtonItem;
```

Then, when you want to show the master view controller, make a call like this:

```
[barButtonForMaster.target performSelector: barButtonForMaster.action withObject: barButtonForMaster];
```

In case you want to perform this right at the start, then use some delay in order to prevent app crashing (thanks to the helpful comment):

```
[barButtonForMaster.target performSelector: barButtonForMaster.action withObject: barButtonForMaster afterDelay:1];
```

In that case you can perform the selector right in the split view delegate method.

Comment: thanks, but really what I was asking for is the code for myMethodToShowHideMaster

Comment: This would work if my detail view was embedded in a Navigation Controller, but it is not.  I am using a UIButton on the detail view, not a UIBarButtonItem.  Could you update your answer for a UIButton without the use of a Navigation Controller